# How to let the App give access to App buttons through keypad keys in Android

Tags: android

I am not sure how many people out there are using keypad based phones. But as an app developer we should take care of all these issues right. So in my App I have 3 buttons with icons. Now when I was testing it in emulator I was unable to access these buttons through keypad

Is something to be done in the App for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to and implement your own keyevent to activate this.
I.e. override `public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`.